# Angular2 - How to do an interceptor in order to detect a 500 and 404 error in my app.ts file?

Tags: typescript, angular

**Angular2 - How to do an interceptor in order to detect a 500 and 404 error in my app.ts file?**

I want to detect a 500 or 404 error in my app.ts file so I can do a redirect to my html 404 and html 500 pages accordingly.

Is this possible.
I could do it in angular 1.x

**Would this work?**

```
    this.router.subscribe((currentRoute, error) => {
        if(error){
             //do redirect here???
        }

    })
```

Thank you.

Comment: this seems to be currently an open point of discussion, see here -> https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2684

Comment: If you're talking about Http requests, they already throw so you can catch the error in `subscribe((success) => ..., (error) => /* redirect here */)`

Comment: Hi Eric Martinez - I've added the code above - does that look right?

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my project to redirect to a 404 page.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/tryagain', name: '404', component: NotFoundComponent},
    {path:'/**', redirectTo: ['404']}
])
```

Just a quick solution. you can also use it to route to your home page and have a banner saying the page is not found.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path:'/**', redirectTo: ['Home', {error: 'not found'}] }
])
```

In home component check for the error routing param and handle it gracefully.

Comment: is "NotFoundComponent" a reserved word or is that actually a component? if so whats in the component?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated to RC.3**

In the current version of **Angular 2.0.0-rc.3** I use the `'**'` path a to define a *catch all* path (e.g. to show a 404 page or redirect the user to the default page like the one provided by the `LoginCompinent`).

```
@Routes([
  { path: '',                         component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register',                 component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'confirm/:value1/:value2',  component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'home',                     component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**',                       component: My404Component }
])
```

Take care that this is always the last entry in your list:

```
  { path: '**',                       component: My404Component }
```